# How to create a docker image with non linux OS distribution

Tags: docker

Apologies if this is not the right channel for this question but hopefully someone can clarify my confusion.

So I am trying to containerze a java application currently running (not on container) on AIX operating system.

So, my confusion goes is:

1. Will I be able to ever do this migration without replatforming and migrating to some version of linux and keeping the same OS (AIX unix) intact? If yes then, what kind of base OS image I'll be able to use for AIX and will it ever be able to use resources of the host OS kernel which is always linux?
2. Is it true that base OS image has to be some flavor of linux for it to consume the underlying linux kernel of host OS? If this is true then how are folks running a .net application in docker which runs on windows?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Read documentation online but didn't get any concrete resolution of my confusion.

Comment: Docker heavily depends on Linux-specific features like cgroups, so it doesn't work on other plaforms.

Comment: what about .net? I have seen .net applications getting containerized and those only run on windows.

Comment: I think you have a point here: to use Docker it is either Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Docker support for AIX was requested in 2015 ([`moby/moby` issue 11680](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11680)) and studied by [IBM, using IBM POWER](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/d-docker-on-power-linux-platform/) also in 2015.

More recently (2019), IBM proposes [enter link description here](https://ibmsystemsmag.com/Power-Systems/06/2019/kubernetes-management-aix), which uses AIX Workload Partitions (WPARs), an OS-specific container technology.

If your current AIX-compatible image can use WPAR, it might no run on a Linux-host kernel: system calls could differ.

Comment: but the host os is still linux here. Wondering even if I somehow make AIX based image docker container, would it ever work as the underlying kernel is linux? My understanding is that when I lift and shift from an AIX based system to a container based system, it would run on linux and not what is there in dockerfile (base os)

Comment: @RayS Then it is not guarantee that your current AIX-compatible image can run on a Linux host kernel: system calls might not be the same.

Comment: Is it true that the docker container has to has to run on a host os with linux kernel?

Comment: @RayS If it makes Linux system calls yes. A Windows application would need to run (in a Docker container) on a Windows host.

Comment: Does windows host support docker?

Comment: @RayS Yes, both for Windows container and, through HyperV, Linux containers (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)